# How do I convert a VMDK disk to QCOW2 using qemu-img without inflating the disk?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, disk-image

I'm converting some VMs from vSphere to KVM/QEMU but each time it inflates the thin provisioned disk.

Before converting the image from `vmdk` to `qcow2`, first I export OVAs or OVFs from vSphere to make sure disks are consolidated and ready to go.

In `qemu-img --help`, there's a `-c` option for "compress" but that document is somewhere between ambiguous to downright confusing, it doesn't specify if it's a general option a snapshot option, it says it's for "qcow", but does that mean `qcow` & `qcow2` or specifically just `qcow`? — It talks about both in a list item that converts without warning in a sublist.

Furthermore, `compress` is listed as a format too, in addition to `qcow2`.

I thought one of, if not the main features of the qcowX format was to create thin provision disks (without sparse files).

Could you help me out with the correct syntax, please? Currently I'm using:

```bash
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 image.vmdk image.qcow2
```

…
which I took from the [OpenStack documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html).

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Using:

```bash
qemu-img convert -cp -O qcow2 image.qcow2 image-compressed.qcow2
```

I got a disk almost exactly in size like the exported VMDK—it wasn't as fast as zero punching with `vmkfstools` though. I have not tested it yet but it seems this might be it.

**UPDATE 2**

That was the correct option, but:

1. I forgot adding the drivers before exporting the VM, which I could've managed except that,
2. …my question was how to convert from VMDK to QCOW2, not QCOW2 to thin QCOW2. So, I had to verify.

The command is:

```bash
qemu-img convert -cpf vmdk -O qcow2 <source-file> <output-file>
```

Where:

- `-c` is for compressed, which is I guess compresses zeros into zero because input is the same size as output.
- `-p` shows progress. It takes forever, so this is needed to not go insane, or at least to prevent cancelling it thinking it's frozen.
- `-f` specifies input format.
- `-O` specifies output format.

[image: Check out the timestamps]

> BTW, it shouldn't matter what the OS is, Linux supports VirtIO natively, and Windows, well… is Windows. A decent hypervisor won't export a VM that will generate an unusable output. If it doesn't work regardless, just change the storage bus in the destination hypervisor, e.g; SCSI, SATA, VirtIO, NVMe, VMware Paravirtual, IDE, etc.

Hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: Not sure if it's important, are these VM's Windows or Linux? I ask because I think I had the same issue when dealing with windows images - though, I was working with XenServer garbage

Comment: you have answered your own question, that is a good thing, but you should post the answer part as an answer, not include it in the question part.

Comment: I'm using two tools for the conversion. Backup and restore with Veeam or Starwinds V2V converter with the P2V option. Hope it helps. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter

https://www.veeam.com/